# Click function only when user isn't hovering on another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**I have the following structure:**
[image]

The whole rectangle is `.msg_box` and the little red X is `.msg_del_x`

**The HTMl of that is (there are multiple of these boxes, all with the same class):**

```
<div class="msg_box" msg_id="4">
    <span style="font-size: 16px">Administartor</span><span class="msg_del_x" del_id="4" style="float: right; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 0.6;">x</span><br>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">d</span><span style="float: right; font-size: 11px; color: #444;">05.09.15</span>
</div>
```

**This is the JS (without the red X)**

```
$(".msg_box").click(function(){
    var msg_id = $(this).attr("msg_id");
    $(".msg_box").css("background-color", "#FFF");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#EEE");
    $("#msg_display").load("select.php?msg_id="+msg_id);
    $("#msg_display").css("background-color", "#EEE");
})
```

**This is my current JS for the red X `.msg_del_x`**

```
$(".msg_del_x").click(function(){
    //AJAX
});
```

**The Problem**

The problem is that if I click on any `.msg_del_x` the `.msg_box` is also clicked which starts the first JS I posted. And I don't want that.

If I click on the red X (`.msg_del_x`), the click-event of `.msg_box` shouldn't start.

I thought this could be made with hover-checks but this didn't worked for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The function **[event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** prevents the click on a child element getting bubbled to any parent elements.

```
$(".msg_del_x").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```